# Show that 2 has ramification index 4 on field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I'm stuck at the item (b) in this quadratic number field question:

[image]

I tried writing $\mathfrak{P}$ as $(1+i) \mathcal{O}_K + 
(1+\alpha) \mathcal{O}_K$ (that is the ideal generated by two elements, right?) and squaring it, but couldn't find anything that would solve this problem.

Comment: $(1+i,1+a)^2=((1+i)^2,(1+a)^2,(1+i)(1+a))$

Comment: And how does it prove that $2 \mathcal{O}_k = \mathfrak{P}^4$?

Comment: Do the computation, $(1+i)^2=2i$ so you can reduce everything $\bmod 2$, so you can replace $\sqrt{2m}$ by $\sqrt{2}$ and $1+i$ by $\sqrt{2i}$, you should get $(1+i,1+a)^2 =(2,1+i)$